# Installing Sql Server 2012 on Vmware Virtual Server 2008 R2

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server

I have a Virtual Windows Server 2008 R2 set up, I downloaded Sql Server 2012 Evaluation Copy. Now when I try to Install the Sql Server it throws an error, No Error message nothing at all just an error window pops up with no information at all.

Can anyone suggest me what is going on and how to fix this? thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you met all the prerequisites? Make sure you have SP1 installed as well as .Net 3.5
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx

Comment: It was a corrupted iso file, I had to download it again.